# Ansible Collect task list and print if any task has failed

Tags: ansible, vmware

In ansible, inside a inner loop I am performing below activities and registering results

```
 - name: Check the nslookup status 
   shell: nslookup mydomain.com
   register: nslookup_result
   ignore_errors: yes

 - name: Check the Time date status
   shell: timedatectl status 
   register: timedatectl_result
   ignore_errors: yes 

- name: Check Date
  shell: date
  register: date_result
  ignore_errors: yes
```

I am trying to print summary of the any of the task failed.

```
- name: Summary of Jobs
  set_facts:
    failed_tests: "{{ failed_tests| default([]) + 'The server has been failed with errors [failed_result.stdout]' }}"
  fail:
    msg: The server has been failed with errors "{{ failed_result.stdout }}"
  when: failed_result.failed is true
  loop:
    - nslookup_result
    - timedatectl_result
    - date_result
  loop_control:
     loop_var: failed_result


- name: Check any test job failed
  fail:
    msg: Some job failed
  when: failed_tests.length() >= 1

- name: Print the list of the failed tests
    var=unsuccessful_tasks
  loop: failed_tests
  loop_control:
    loop_var: unsuccessful_tasks
```

Can someone help on this as this task has been failed.

Comment: What is the failure message you're getting, when you run the playbook?

Answer (score 0):

First the failed jobs print the failure message to different output attributes, sometimes in `stderr` and sometimes in `stdout`.
Example:

```yaml
ok: [test-001] => {
        "rc": 1,
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "Server:\t\tx.x.x.x\nAddress:\tx.x.x.x#53\n\n** server can't find do.yes: NXDOMAIN",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Server:\t\tx.x.x.x",
            "Address:\tx.x.x.x#53",
            "",
            "** server can't find do.yes: NXDOMAIN"
        ]
    }
}
ok: [test-001] => {
        "rc": 1,
        "stderr": "cat: /tmp/t: No such file or directory",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "cat: /tmp/t: No such file or directory"
        ],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```

you should start with `stderr`, and when it's empty print `stdout`.
Plus you're using the loop and condition a wrong way.
You can use the return value `rc` to check the failed task.

> Some modules execute command line utilities or are geared for executing commands directly (raw, shell, command, and so on), this field contains ‘return code’ of these utilities.

```yaml
- name: Summary of Jobs
  debug:
    msg: "The server has been failed with errors {{ item.stderr_lines if item.stderr_lines | length > 0 else item.stdout_lines }}"
  loop:
    - "{{ nslookup_result }}"
    - "{{ timedatectl_result }}"
    - "{{ date_result }}"
  when: item.rc != 0
```

```yaml
TASK [Summary of Jobs] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': True, 'stdout': "Server:\t\tx.x.x.x\nAddress:\tx.x.x.x#53\n\n** server can
't find do.yes: NXDOMAIN", 'stderr': '', 'rc': 1, 'cmd': 'nslookup do.yes', 'start': '2022-10-16 00:26:40.297689', 'end
': '2022-10-16 00:26:40.381663', 'delta': '0:00:00.083974', 'failed': True, 'msg': 'non-zero return code', 'stdout_lines
': ['Server:\t\tx.x.x.x', 'Address:\tx.x.x.x#53', '', "** server can't find do.yes: NXDOMAIN"], 'stderr_lines'
: []}) => {
    "msg": "The server has been failed with errors ['Server:\\t\\tx.x.x.x', 'Address:\\tx.x.x.x#53', '', \"** server can't find do.yes: NXDOMAIN\"]"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': True, 'stdout': '', 'stderr': 'cat: /tmp/t: No such file or directory', 'rc': 1, '
cmd': 'cat /tmp/t', 'start': '2022-10-16 00:26:40.580334', 'end': '2022-10-16 00:26:40.584115', 'delta': '0:00:00.00378
1', 'failed': True, 'msg': 'non-zero return code', 'stdout_lines': [], 'stderr_lines': ['cat: /tmp/t: No such file or d
irectory']}) => {
    "msg": "The server has been failed with errors ['cat: /tmp/t: No such file or directory']"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'changed': True, 'stdout': 'Sun Oct 16 00:26:40 CEST 2022', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'cmd
': 'date', 'start': '2022-10-16 00:26:40.779088', 'end': '2022-10-16 00:26:40.782367', 'delta': '0:00:00.003279', 'msg'
: '', 'stdout_lines': ['Sun Oct 16 00:26:40 CEST 2022'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False})
```

Comment: Can you please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090591/process-ansible-in-memory-inventory